# How to animate navigation in Android Wear OS Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

What I want is some screen transition code with a sliding animation.

```
val navController = rememberSwipeDismissableNavController()

SwipeDismissableNavHost(
                navController = swipeDismissableNavController,
                startDestination = Screen.FirstScreen.route,
                modifier = modifier
            ) {

composable(route = Screen.FirstScreen.route) {
   navController.navigate(Screen.SecondScreen.route)
}

composable(route = Screen.SecondScreen.route)
.
.

}
```

**How do I handle animation here?**

```
val option = NavOptions.Builder()
                            .setEnterAnim(R.anim.slide_in_left)
                            .setExitAnim(R.anim.slide_out_right)
                            .build()
                        
navController.navigate(Screen.RecordNotUploadScreen.route, option)
```

**This code doesn't work**

Comment: I'm having the same question / issue. I doubt if navigation animation is implemented for Wear? Can anyone confirm if it is / isn't?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code to achieve screen transitions with sliding animations in Android Wear OS Compose:

```kotlin
val navController = rememberSwipeDismissableNavController()

SwipeDismissableNavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = Screen.FirstScreen.route,
    modifier = modifier
) {
    composable(route = Screen.FirstScreen.route) {
        // Your content for the first screen
        Button(onClick = {
            navController.navigate(Screen.SecondScreen.route)
        }) {
            Text("Go to Second Screen")
        }
    }

    composable(route = Screen.SecondScreen.route) {
        // Your content for the second screen
        // ...
    }
}
```

To handle animations, you can use the `rememberAnimatedNavController` provided by Compose Navigation. Make sure you have the appropriate navigation dependencies added to your project. Here's an example:

```kotlin
val navController = rememberAnimatedNavController()

SwipeDismissableNavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = Screen.FirstScreen.route,
    modifier = modifier
) {
    // Composables for each screen
}

// Define your animation resources (slide_in_left.xml and slide_out_right.xml) in the res/anim directory

// Then use NavOptions to specify animations when navigating
val option = NavOptions.Builder()
    .setEnterAnim(R.anim.slide_in_left)
    .setExitAnim(R.anim.slide_out_right)
    .build()

navController.navigate(Screen.SecondScreen.route, options = option)
```

Ensure that you have the slide_in_left.xml and slide_out_right.xml animation files defined in the `res/anim` directory of your Android Wear OS project. These files should contain appropriate animation definitions for your sliding animation effect.

Comment: Are you using "com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation"?

If you use this, the first screen will not appear.

Comment: Not sure if rememberAnimatedNavController is intended for Wear Apps