# Best practice for compose Wear OS App navigation

Tags: android-studio, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os

I've developed a Wear OS app some time ago with Android Studio using the view system. I'm now looking into compose and it's giving me some challenges.

First I'm looking at the navigation in the App. To clarify how this works in my App, I've created a small drawing. My App's main screen is most important, is full screen and will not scroll (as per design).
[image]

**Current (View System) situation**

In the view system I'm using the WearableNavigationDrawer (you pull it down from the top and then swipe left / right between pages and tap to select one) to navigate between the screens at the top. This invokes the NavController to navigate to the various fragments.

For the actionlist on screen one I'm using the WearableActionDrawer, which comes up with a swipe from the bototm of the main screen. You select an action and it disappears.

**Compose challenges**

I'm only just trying to mimic the UI (without functionality) with compose. So building the UI screens and try to navigate between them.

I started with a compose sample App from the Google website. This uses a WearNavScaffold from the horologist libraries with a SwipeDismissableNavController for navigation. **This is where I get stuck**.

Inside the WearNavScaffold I've added a MainScreen, which basically adds a HorizontalPager and includes all the top Screens depending on which page the user is. Some of the screens (with a max. 5) have scrollable content, and others not. This way the user can swipe from left to right to navigate between the horizontal pages.

**Possible problem**

I guess I'm not implementing this correctly, since these screens are not 'navigated to' with the NavController. I'm also getting some strange behavior since the WearNavScaffold columnState is used by multiple screens / pages.

**Question**

I don't want to change the structure of the App too much and there's very (very) little room left on the Main Screen to add something else, so how should this be implemented properly?

1. Can I use the navcontroller inside the HorizontalPager or is that not a good practice?
2. Or should I ditch the HorizontalPager and mimic it's use by
   detecting left/right swipe gestures to navigate to the appropriate
   page with animation?

**UPDATE**

In the meantime I can answer my own two question. A horizontal pages to switch between pages is a bad idea. So I tried to implement swiping left and right to navigate between the top screens. I've added some dots at the bottom of the display to show the use which "page" he/she is on. This has its downside that navigation animation doesn't seem to work for compose on Wear (yet): [How to animate navigation in Android Wear OS Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77035268/how-to-animate-navigation-in-android-wear-os-compose)

Another option is to mimic the WearableNavigationDrawer that is available in the view system for Wear. I managed to get this working to a point where I can pull down a box that has a horizontal pager and navigate to a top level screen. Issue here is that when I end up on a screen that has a Column or a ScalingLazyColumn, the detectDragGestures pulldown swipe gesture is not picked up.

Looking at these three options the last two a serious contenders. Out of these two the swping left and right is the most user friendly / quickest. Only drawback (soon to be resolved I hope) is that there is no animation during navigation. But hopefully this will be resolved soon when compose becomes more mature for Wear.

What do you think?

**Final update**

First I have to say that Google is not very helpful on this topic. For the view system they had a component, which was very limited, but a similar component seems to be missing for compose.

So after a lot of trial and error I came to the conclusion that swiping lef/right is not the way forward (Google policies require a right swipe to navigate back or to close the App). So I ended up mimicking the WearableNavigationDrawer.

The hardest part was to capture the vertical swipes on screens where there is ScalingLazyColumn, which captures / consumes all pointer changes. To get around this I created a class that implements PointerInputModifierNode, Modifier.Node() to capture the PointerEvents regardsless of the pointerInput of the ScalingLazyColumn.

So this enables me to add a drop-down screen to all top-level screens with a swipe-down (this drop-down is not in my picture). For each top-level screen I added an icon on this drop down, so I can navigate to each of these 4 top-level screens. With a right swipe, the user navigates back (or uses the drop-down again).

And on the Main screen I did the same for the actions screen that swipes up from the bottom. This seems to work nicely. Still a bit too much repetitive code for the 4 top-level screens for my taste, but hey, it works.